Why $TIME(2^{n^k})\nsubseteq NTIME(n^k)$?
There is a theorem that said for every nondeterministic Turing machine that runs in $O(n^k)$ there is an equivalent deterministic Turing machine that runs in $O(2^{n^k})$.
From this theorem, I understand that $NTIME(n^k)\subseteq TIME(2^{n^k})$.
Why doesn't the other direction hold?
i.e., why for every deterministic Turing machine that runs in $O(2^{n^k})$ we can't construct nondeterministic Turing machine that runs in $O(n^k)$ ?

Just to be precise, there is an equivalent deterministic machine that runs in $2^{O(n^k)}$, not necessarily $O(2^{n^k}).$

If $\mathsf{TIME}(2^{n^k})\subseteq \mathsf{NTIME}(n^k)$, that would mean that $\mathsf{EXP} = \mathsf{NP}$, which is an open problem.
I don't think that means that this inclusion doesn't hold, just that we don't know the answer.

Hello Nathaniel! Do you have any intuition to why exponential deterministic TM can't be translated consistently to polynomial non-deterministic polynomial TM? I understand the part of $EXP=NP$ but there are miracles thing that associated with nondeterminism (from the equivalents of DFA and NFA, and the translation of polynomial nondeterministic TM to exponential deterministic TM) that made me believe maybe there is a translation like this and I just don't see it.

@Daniel Using non-determinism to do an exponential amount of stuff in polynomial time seems dependent on the ability to "parallelize" that stuff.

@Daniel also “a miracle could happen and I just don’t see it” is a pretty good summary of many open questions in complexity theory.

@spaceisdarkgreen Can you elaborate on "the ability to parallelize that stuff" ?

@Daniel  NP-complete problems tend to have this structure where a brute force solution involves an exponentially long search with a polynomial inner loop, where the inner loops are independent of one another. This seems a lot more specific than just knowing it takes an exponential time to run. For a sense of how generic the general case is, consider the problem of determining from input $(M,x,k)$ whether the computation $M(x)$ halts within $k$ steps. This is an EXP-complete problem. (My point being that we seem to have to break down "arbitrary behavior" in this specific way.)

@spaceisdarkgreen Thank you!
